# <strong> tag using TCPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I'm having a hard time generating PDFs with TCPDF. Generally, everything works fine, but, sometimes when I use the `<strong>` tag, everything gets messed up.

I have 2 examples here:

http://ontheweb.com.br/pdf/ex2.pdf

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but this might be related:

> The problem arises when using
>   justify property AND there are some line breaks AND bold. The justify
>   proccess seems to have some problems if the firsts words of the next line
>   are bold.

Via http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2903137&group_id=128076&atid=710532

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug now solved. Just upgrade.
Check the TCPDF website at http://www.tcpdf.org and consult the official forum for further information.