# TCPDF: Severe formatting bug with writeHtml

Tags: php, tcpdf

Look at this code:

```
    $pdf->Ln(4);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(200, 220, 255);
    $pdf->Cell(180, 6, 'Education', 0, 1, '', 1);
    $pdf->Ln(4);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

    $html = '
     Degree ......................  <strong>' . $education->degree_title . '</strong>
    <br/>
    Graduation Date .............  ' . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($education->award_date)) . '
    <br/>
    Attendance ..................  ' . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($education->school_start_date)) . ' - ' . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($education->school_end_date)) . '
    <br/>';

    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Because it's running when the setting is:

```
$pdf->setCellMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
```

The end result is:

[image]

As you can see, the html `<strong>` causes the part of the HTML that is to be bolded, to be influenced by the "30" value in the setCellMargins. IF you don't use `<strong>` or any other HTML element for that matter the formatting is fine.

Is there any way around this bug? I don't want to stop using the left cell margin, and i certainly don't want to discontinue using bold in my PDF.

Comment: I don't know if this is the same as your question, but it seems like it was a bug based on this post and has been resolved with a TCPDF update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058419/strong-tag-using-tcpdf

Comment: I've got the latest version of TCPDF. This can't be it. And it happens even if I use <span> or any html tag.

Comment: If you strip out all code other than the $html and the $pdf->writeHtml and try to view the pdf, does it behave the same? My experience with TCPDF hasn't been much different than yours, with lots of random weird seemingly unrelated strange behavior. I would usually strip it down to bare bones when I had issues and put my code into one of their examples that 'work' and see if the same behavior persists (http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps as a starting point)

Comment: Yes. as you can see from the "graduation date" line which behaves normally. the only difference between correct and "weird" behavior is the addition of <strong></strong> around a word. **I eventually gave up and formatted the printing with CSS and Print media**